# Induction to prove the following Congruency?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction

I'm pretty much stuck and I'm obviously missing some hint to come up with a proof for the following problem:

Given the series

$$\ a_0 =1$$
$$\ a_n =4(a_{n-1}+1)$$

I want to show that
$a_n\equiv 1\pmod 7 $ for all $n$

I calculated these:

$\ a_0 =1,
a_1=8,
a_2=36, a_3 =148$

The **base** is clear, we take $n = 1$, then we get
$$\ a_1 = 4(a_{n-1}+1) = 4(a_{1-1}+1)=4(a_{0}+1)=4(1+1)=8$$

Afterwards i continued with:

$n \to n+1$

$$a_{n+1} = 4(a_{n}+1)$$

We can replace $a_n$ with $4(a_{n-1}+1)$

$$a_{n+1} = 4(4(a_{n-1}+1)+1)$$
or
$$a_{n+1} = 16(a_{n-1})+20$$

How should I proceed from here on? Is there another way to prove this problem?
I see that it is recursive - I'm just kind of stuck.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: By linked  [congruence laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\bmod 7\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{a_n\equiv 1}\Rightarrow a_{n+1} = 4(\color{#c00}{a_n}+1)\equiv 4(\color{#c00}1+1)\equiv 8\equiv 1\,$  [the inductive step].

Answer (score 0):

$a_n \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \implies (a_n + 1) \equiv 2 \pmod{7} \implies $

$a_{n+1} = 4(a_n + 1) \equiv 1 \pmod{7}.$

The idea is that $8 \equiv 1\pmod{7}.$

Comment: :O ... beautiful

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).